# How can I cast numbers propely in Scala?

Tags: json, scala

I need to put some numeric value into an JSON array. But every time I use obj.put("key", value) the value is automatically "casted" into Integer.

i.e.

value = 0.0 => {"key": 0}

I want the value in the JSON object to be EXACTLY the same of the value I get from the application.

I thought of using value.getClass in order to get the value of the class and create a match...case method and use value.toString.to*, where * is the corresponding class (i.e the class is Integer, the value will be casted using value.toString.toInt). But this approach is kinda "dirty" in my opinion, and I'm new to Scala so I don't know this language very well and its tricks.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: Here's the code (here I send the JSON to a server):

```
for ((p, v) <- exportMap){
        val obj: JSONObject = new JSONObject()
        obj.put("path", parsePathString(p.toString))
        if (v.toString.equals("Infinity")) {
            obj.put("result", "Inf")
        } else {
            obj.put("result", v)
        }
        exportJSONArray.put(obj)
```

Here I get the JSON from the server, in order to use its data in the app:

```
var result: Any = jSONObject.get("result")
        if (result.equals("Inf")) {
            result = Double.PositiveInfinity
        }
```

and then the variable "result" goes in a data structure.

So I need to have the EXACT same type of numeric data.

Comment: Please share exact code you are using.

Comment: @Pavel Just edited the question.

Comment: `0.0` and `0` is _exactly the same_ double value. If you need a string in a particular format, you will have to store it as a string.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? How are we supposed to know how this `put` method works?

Comment: @laughedelic I'm using "org.JSON".

Comment: `org.JSON` is not a name of library. I guess, you mean [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library.

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to have the EXACT same type of numeric data

First of all, you want *exact* same type, but type is as `Any`. It's like saying that you don't care about the type. You can use [`optDouble`](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#optDouble-java.lang.String-double-) getter for it:

```
val result: Double = jSONObject.optDouble("result", Double.PositiveInfinity)
```

(and it doesn't have to be a `var`, try not to use vars in Scala)

Next, in the part where you write to the object, you can check whether the value is infinity:

```
obj.put("result", if(v.isInfinity) "Inf" else v)
```

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: What if the values I'm sending to the server aren't Double only? What if a value in that map is an Integer?

Comment: It's all the same. Just use the corresponding getter: `optInt` for integer, or `optBoolean`, etc. In some cases instead of infinity you will get something else, like NaN, how you deal with it depends on your application.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But don't I need a method/something that can tell me what type of numeric data I'm going to get from the JSON? i.e a value from the JSON is "5", so I can use `optInt`instead of `optDouble`, another value I can get from the JSON is "5.6", so I need too use `optDouble`. Is there a way to do that, except doing a string matching with the name of the class?

Comment: Look, to be honest, so far you kind of fail to ask your question. You should read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and try again. Improve the original question, make clear what you want to do, what is the problem, how have you tried to solve it and so on.

Comment: Regarding questions in your last comment, why do you want to derive type from a random string value? You are supposed to know your data, each key should have a stable type: `result` in your example is double, some other key has string values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are very many JSON libraries in Java (and Scala), and you picked one which [intentionally does this](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java#L943-L962):

```
public static String numberToString(Number number) throws JSONException {
    if (number == null) {
        throw new JSONException("Null pointer");
    }
    testValidity(number);

    // Shave off trailing zeros and decimal point, if possible.

    String string = number.toString();
    if (string.indexOf('.') > 0 && string.indexOf('e') < 0
            && string.indexOf('E') < 0) {
        while (string.endsWith("0")) {
            string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
        }
        if (string.endsWith(".")) {
            string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

You can pick a different one which doesn't.